# Blocks in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have simple makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = f1.h,hellomake.h



$(info starting makefile )

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(info executing)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o 
        gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o -I.
```

I expect `executing` line to be printed on each object file generation. But this not happening. Where is my mistake.

Comment: The comma in `DEPS` is incorrect. You are specifying a file name of `f1.h,hellomake.h` which doesn't exist so make is ignoring your rule and using the built-in rule instead. Run `make -r` and you should get `no rule to make `hellomake.o` or something like that.

Comment: You also may want to change your usage of `info` (an 'info-page' viewer) to `echo` (an output displayerer..er..er).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your Makefile:

```
$(info executing)
```

With this line:

```
@echo "executing"
```